# lftp mirror -I and mirror -i don't work

Tags: linux, ftp, mirroring, lftp

I am using the following command lines to mirror a remote server to my local directory:

```
$ lftp -d -c 'open -e "mirror -i ^ABC .  mirrordir/" http://ftp.abc.com/dir1/dir2'

$ lftp -d -c 'open -e "mirror -I ABC*/ . mirrordir/ "http://ftp.abc.com/dir1/dir2'
```

Both do not work.

Please note that I only want directories starting with `ABC` to be mirrored.

Moreover these commands also do not work

```
$ lftp ftp.abc.com:/inbound/ftp> ls  ABC*/
```

gives

```
ls: Access failed: 404 Not Found (ABC*/)
```

and this

```
$ lftp ftp.abc.com:/inbound/ftp> ls  ABC*
```

gives

```
ls: Access failed: 404 Not Found (ABC*)
```

after I execute them from the lftp prompt after connecting like this:

```
$ lftp -d -e open 'http://ftp.abc.com/dir1/dir2'
```

Where am I going wrong ?